# How to Transform a Pandas DataFrame with Multi-Level Columns into a Single-Level Column DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with multi-level columns like the one below:

|  |  |  |  | 23-Jan |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 23-Feb |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Market | Product | City | Territory | VALUES | Values MARKET SHARE | VALUES GROWTH | VALUES GEO. SHARE | UNITS | UNITS MARKET SHARE | UNITS GROWTH | UNITS GEO. SHARE | VALUES | Values MARKET SHARE | VALUES GROWTH | VALUES GEO. SHARE | UNITS | UNITS MARKET SHARE | UNITS GROWTH | UNITS GEO. SHARE |

[image]
I want to create a Python function that transforms this DataFrame into the following format:

| Market | Product | City | Territory | VALUES | Values MARKET SHARE | VALUES GROWTH | VALUES GEO. SHARE | UNITS | UNITS MARKET SHARE | UNITS GROWTH | UNITS GEO. SHARE | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 23-Jan |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 23-Feb |

[image]
How can I achieve this transformation using Python and Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to help when the `MultiIndex` constructor is not available. You can reshape dataframe using `stack` and some index methods:

```
>>> (df.set_index(df.columns[:4].tolist())  # Market, Product, City, Territory
       .rename_axis(index=df.columns[:4].droplevel(0),  # Flat them
                    columns=['Date', None])  # Define column names
       .stack('Date', sort=False).reset_index())  # Reshape your dataframe

   Market  Product  City  Territory    Date  VALUES  Values MARKET SHARE  VALUES GROWTH  VALUES GEO. SHARE  UNITS  UNITS MARKET SHARE  UNITS GROWTH  UNITS GEO. SHARE
0       0        0     0          0  23-Jan       1                    1              1                  1      1                   1             1                 1
1       0        0     0          0  23-Feb       2                    2              2                  2      2                   2             2                 2
```

Minimal Working Example:

```
data = {('', 'Market'): {0: 0},
 ('', 'Product'): {0: 0},
 ('', 'City'): {0: 0},
 ('', 'Territory'): {0: 0},
 ('23-Jan', 'VALUES'): {0: 1},
 ('23-Jan', 'Values MARKET SHARE'): {0: 1},
 ('23-Jan', 'VALUES GROWTH'): {0: 1},
 ('23-Jan', 'VALUES GEO. SHARE'): {0: 1},
 ('23-Jan', 'UNITS'): {0: 1},
 ('23-Jan', 'UNITS MARKET SHARE'): {0: 1},
 ('23-Jan', 'UNITS GROWTH'): {0: 1},
 ('23-Jan', 'UNITS GEO. SHARE'): {0: 1},
 ('23-Feb', 'VALUES'): {0: 2},
 ('23-Feb', 'Values MARKET SHARE'): {0: 2},
 ('23-Feb', 'VALUES GROWTH'): {0: 2},
 ('23-Feb', 'VALUES GEO. SHARE'): {0: 2},
 ('23-Feb', 'UNITS'): {0: 2},
 ('23-Feb', 'UNITS MARKET SHARE'): {0: 2},
 ('23-Feb', 'UNITS GROWTH'): {0: 2},
 ('23-Feb', 'UNITS GEO. SHARE'): {0: 2}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
                                23-Jan                      ...        23-Feb                                                                         
  Market Product City Territory VALUES Values MARKET SHARE  ... VALUES GROWTH VALUES GEO. SHARE UNITS UNITS MARKET SHARE UNITS GROWTH UNITS GEO. SHARE
0      0       0    0         0      1                   1  ...             2                 2     2                  2            2                2

[1 rows x 20 columns]
```

Comment: That got it right, Thank you